# Setting fn key as Ctrl on Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard, osx-snow-leopard

I am having difficulty in using **Ctrl** key on emacs. Because,  <kbd>fn</kbd> key resides in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key's location on my new keyboard.

What should I do to map <kbd>fn</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is controlled by the variable `ns-function-modifier`, however, as I don't use a laptop I haven't had the opportunity to play around with it.

I guess that you should set it to something like:

```
(setq ns-function-modifier 'control)
```

Comment: @DiegoSaa, Maybe you are using an older version of Emacs? Try getting a newer one from www.emacsformacosx.com

Comment: @Lindydancer, Actually, I have version 24.3.1, but I compiled it from source... In my case, emacs ignores the fn key.

Comment: @DiegoSaa, I just checked out and built the Emacs trunk from the bzr trunk; here it works...

Comment: @DiegoSaa `(setq mac-function-modifier 'control)` works for me

Answer (score 2):

There's a lovely new feature in EMACS 23 -- customize the group "ns" and you can set all the key mappings very conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not just for Emacs, but for the command line, too.

1. DoubleCommand.   The solution I have been using for years is to install [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/). It is a free download and allows you to map any key to any other key.  You do have to start it after logging out or shutting down, so I keep it on my Desktop.
2. MacOS Keyboard.  In MacOS 13.1, They now allow you to map the function key to the control key.   System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Tab > Modifier Keys Button - and there it is.